# UIScrollview zoom refresh content

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, zooming

I am currently using a uiscrollview to zoom views in and out. If I have a textview, the font becomes blurred after it is zoomed in. Can I force the content to refresh? i.e setneedsdislay ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to modify this behavior in scrollView delegate method -

```
- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView
```

or

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView*)scrollView withView:(UIView*)view atScale:(float)relScale
```

Check out the [CATiledLayer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/ScrollViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html) example provided by the ScrollViewSuite sample code.

The TapToZoom example illustrates a way to get the view to redraw its content when one zooms in. I.e. you need to somehow set your view's frame to be larger than the screen, or maybe you can also use transforms - however, I never used transforms before.

Comment: Thanks been trying to download it but it is taking forever. 74mb 3hrs!

Comment: Still downloading lol and found that I can subclass the class i want to draw with more details and return a CATILEDLAYER. What is your take on this? I tried it and it works.

Comment: if you are using just `UIScrollView` & some `UIViews` inside then I suggest you stick to these delegate methods. They are safe, tried & tested. That's why they are there. Are you doing something with `CATiledLayer` in `UIScrollView` ?

Comment: Basically I got a textview and when I zoom the text inside is blurry. I tried resetting the contentsize and font but no luck, still burry + I am still downloading that code.

Comment: then i suggest to stay away from `CATiledLayer`. You have to basically redraw the area after zoom. You can see the code in the browser itself. no need to download... the above link has code viewer...

Comment: Okay thanks. I tried setting the font size to something else. i.e I started with size 5 then doubled it to 10 when it was zoomed in but the font still feels blurry.